# Change rich:modalpanel width/height using JS?

Tags: richfaces, jboss-4.2.x, richfaces-modal

It it possible ? If so, does anyone have any example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not very useful to downvote and not tell why guys ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is js API provided by richfaces for this. If you view page source you'll notice many nested div-s the modal panel consists of, and they have set size in pixels (doesn't matter the modal has autosized=true or no). May be you can adjust size of those divs, but, of course, its a bad way. (I'm using richfaces 3.3.3)

Comment: I know it's not a very 'elegant' way of doing it, but that's what I am trying to do, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Javascript API](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Panels.html#sect-Component_Reference-richpopupPanel-JavaScript_API) for resize popup panel in Richfaces 4.3.x.

```
function changePanelSize() {
    var modalPanel = #{rich:component('PanelName')};
    modalPanel.setLeft(200);
    modalPanel.setTop(200);
    modalPanel.resize(500,800);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In richfaces 3.3.1.SP3 was kind of boring, but I found a solution:

Maximizing rich:modalPanel:

```
var PAD = 30; //const
var idModalPanel = "#{idModalPanel}";
var modal = return #{rich:component(idModalPanel)};
modal.setLeft(PAD);
modal.setTop(PAD);
var width = Richfaces.getWindowSize().width - (2 * PAD);
var height = Richfaces.getWindowSize().height - (2 * PAD);
modal.getContentElement().style.width = width + "px";
modal.getContentElement().style.height = height + "px";
//Update the modal points. That's the trick!
var borders = modal.borders;
for (var i = 0; i < borders.length; i++) {
    b = borders[i];
    b.startDrag(b.sizer);
    b.doDrag(b.id);
    b.endDrag();
}
modal.doResizeOrMove(ModalPanel.Sizer.Diff.EMPTY);
```